# Deeplink won't open app

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm currently working on Deep-Linking and following up interactive posts in my Android App.
I got the following code snippet directly from the Examples:

```
    Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this.getActivity(),getGoogleLoginListener().getPClient())
            .setText("Lemon Cheesecake recipe")
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setContentDeepLinkId("/cheesecake/lemon", /** Deep-link identifier */
                    "Lemon Cheesecake recipe", /** Snippet title */
                    "A tasty recipe for making lemon cheesecake.", /** Snippet description */
                    Uri.parse(imagePath))
            .getIntent();


    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

I also included the Arrival-Activity as described in the docks.
It opens the Share-Dialog and if I share it, it also appears in the G+ Feed.
If I now hit the Entry it will do nothing. If I also provide a Desktop-Url it will just open the browser and visit the Desktop-Url and completely ignores the the deep-link path.
In the Developer Consoloe I do have Deep-Linking enabled on every connected App.

Do I do something wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695264/deep-link-shares-to-google-but-link-does-nothing for what I've tried.